# Create table of yearly monthly temperatures from monthly data

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got a series of tables with monthly data on USA regions over about 130 years, divided by either climate divisions (clim_div) or other federal standards (ncdc_fips). They all follow the same structure, with columns for region, year, and months

```
clim_div, year, january, february, march, april, may, june, july, august, september, october, november, december
```

I want to break things down into very general averages for each region. For example, using the table with monthly minimum temperatures, taking every value from every month of the early years and the later years for each individual region, and giving it one average minimum temperature value. Same for average temp, maximum temp, and precipitation.

```
    state   county  past_minimum recent_minimum past_average recent_average past_maximum recent_maximum past_precip recent_precip
    Alabama Autauga 52.43         52.92         64.25          63.91            76.05       76.18          -0.09       0.1
```

Just doing test SELECTions before creating the table, computing one column took 3 seconds, two columns took 573 seconds. I quit there.
Tried temp tables next, but it looked terrible and still took ~3 seconds per column. I tried CASE in the form of

```
SELECT id.ncdc_fips,
    ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN year < 1931 THEN (january+february+march+april+may+june+july+august+september+october+november+december)/12 END),2) AS past_min
FROM full_ids id
JOIN temps_min mn
GROUP BY ncdc_fips;
```

which worked, but joining the CASE to the full_ids table sent the run time from < 1 second to ~276 seconds. Since I'd also have to add joins for temps_avg, temps_max and precip_1mo, I imagine that would take about a month to run.

Anyway, I did succeed with the following CTEs, and had my table in about 5 seconds.

```
CREATE TABLE county_averages
WITH past_min AS
(
SELECT ncdc_fips, ROUND((AVG(january) + AVG(february) + AVG(march) + AVG(april) + AVG(may) 
    + AVG(june) + AVG(july) + AVG(august) + AVG(september) + AVG(october) + AVG(november) 
    + AVG(december))/12, 2) AS past_minimum
FROM temps_min
WHERE year < 1931
GROUP BY ncdc_fips
),
recent_min AS
(
SELECT ncdc_fips, ROUND((AVG(january) + AVG(february) + AVG(march) + AVG(april) + AVG(may) 
    + AVG(june) + AVG(july) + AVG(august) + AVG(september) + AVG(october) + AVG(november) 
    + AVG(december))/12, 2) AS recent_minimum
FROM temps_min
WHERE year > 1990
GROUP BY ncdc_fips
),
past_avg AS
(
SELECT ncdc_fips, ROUND((AVG(january) + AVG(february) + AVG(march) + AVG(april) + AVG(may) 
    + AVG(june) + AVG(july) + AVG(august) + AVG(september) + AVG(october) + AVG(november) 
    + AVG(december))/12, 2) AS past_average
FROM temps_avg
WHERE year < 1931
GROUP BY ncdc_fips
),
recent_avg AS
(
SELECT ncdc_fips, ROUND((AVG(january) + AVG(february) + AVG(march) + AVG(april) + AVG(may) 
    + AVG(june) + AVG(july) + AVG(august) + AVG(september) + AVG(october) + AVG(november) 
    + AVG(december))/12, 2) AS recent_average
FROM temps_avg
WHERE year < 1990
GROUP BY ncdc_fips
),
past_max AS
(
SELECT ncdc_fips, ROUND((AVG(january) + AVG(february) + AVG(march) + AVG(april) + AVG(may) 
    + AVG(june) + AVG(july) + AVG(august) + AVG(september) + AVG(october) + AVG(november) 
    + AVG(december))/12, 2) AS past_maximum
FROM temps_max
WHERE year < 1931
GROUP BY ncdc_fips
),
recent_max AS
(
SELECT ncdc_fips, ROUND((AVG(january) + AVG(february) + AVG(march) + AVG(april) + AVG(may) 
    + AVG(june) + AVG(july) + AVG(august) + AVG(september) + AVG(october) + AVG(november) 
    + AVG(december))/12, 2) AS recent_maximum
FROM temps_max
WHERE year > 1990
GROUP BY ncdc_fips
),
avg_precip_past AS
(
SELECT clim_div, 
    ROUND((AVG(january) + AVG(february) + AVG(march) + AVG(april) + AVG(may) 
    + AVG(june) + AVG(july) + AVG(august) + AVG(september) + AVG(october) + AVG(november) 
    + AVG(december))/12, 2) AS past_precip
FROM precip_1mo
WHERE year < 1931
GROUP BY clim_div
),
avg_precip_recent AS
(
SELECT clim_div, 
    ROUND((AVG(january) + AVG(february) + AVG(march) + AVG(april) + AVG(may) 
    + AVG(june) + AVG(july) + AVG(august) + AVG(september) + AVG(october) + AVG(november) 
    + AVG(december))/12, 2) AS recent_precip
FROM precip_1mo
WHERE year > 1990
GROUP BY clim_div
)
SELECT state, county, past_minimum, recent_minimum, past_average, recent_average,
        past_maximum, recent_maximum, past_precip, recent_precip
FROM full_ids
JOIN past_min USING (ncdc_fips)
JOIN recent_min USING (ncdc_fips)
JOIN past_avg USING (ncdc_fips)
JOIN recent_avg USING (ncdc_fips)
JOIN past_max USING (ncdc_fips)
JOIN recent_max USING (ncdc_fips)
JOIN avg_precip_past USING (clim_div)
JOIN avg_precip_recent USING (clim_div);
```

1. Had to turn off Code Completion in Preferences to keep Workbench from stalling every few seconds while typing that up.
2. There's got to be a better way, right? 8 CTEs and 8 joins, 80 lines of code for one table?

Anyway. I appreciate any guidance you folks might have on making this more presentable. Thanks!

Comment: There's some review context missing. Cite your reference for "_monthly data on USA regions over about 130 years_". What URL can we download that from? Also, since there's no answers yet, you might want to update so queries use CTEs.

Comment: The data is at https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/pub/data/cirs/climdiv/?C=S;O=D. The files that include tmpccy, tmincy, tmaxcy, sp24dv, and sp01dv. Took some cleaning, though. Is it customary to upload my actual files to github or something when asking here? Honestly I didn't think anybody would go to the trouble of actually running the queries. I'll update the question, too.

Comment: I spent a while on the title when I first posted this, but since the code just creates a table, I struggle to make that sound interesting. It is a little more specific now, at least?

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code is _for_, and removed the concerns about it, per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask) (I assume "too many CTEs" is _not_ a requirement!). Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.